# Does the Thinker know about the power of metas he created?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash* season 4, Thinker forces Barry to come out of the speed force and thus creating 12 different metas who were exposed to dark matter in the bus.

Does he know about the respective powers of each meta beforehand or did he create the metas according to his need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the Thinker himself proclaimed the fact that he has answers to almost anything,  and he knows all the possible future outcomes of any event.

Being a super intelligent meta human, it wouldn't be outrageous to think he calculated how and what powers each of the bus metas were going to get.

Answer (score 1):

The thinker knew about the powers of the metas he created and it is revealed in the season finale that he calculated about all the allies of flash so that even if they come together to fight him with the powers of metas he created he will be able to defeat all of them.He has taken care of Arrow ,Supergirl,Flash ,Cisco and Caitlin's powers.

Comment: Not that Arrow *has* powers, *per se*.